# SSL-how to adjust max frame

Tags: ssl

I read about ssl and it is say that max of ssl frame is 16384bytes is that true?

if true do you know how to adjust it because i have data more than 16384bytes?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I read about ssl and it is say that max of ssl frame is 16384bytes is that true?

No. It has a maximum *SSL message* size of somewhere around there, depending on which cipher suite you use, but the SSL APIs present the SSL socket to you as a byte stream. You don't have to worry about the way SSL packages up writes into SSL messages and back again: it all happens under the hood.

> if true do you know how to adjust it because i have data more than 16384bytes?

Doesn't matter. Just write and read in the usual way.